# How to re-organize vertically listed sales-like data into a better visualized table in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, vlookup

So I came across some data I'd like to re-organize. Unfortunately the source of the data cannot alter anything about what I receive so I cannot change anything in terms of input layout or file type etc.

The data is listed in columns. With Column A being 'Location' B being 'Product' and C being 'Sales'. Unfortunately not all locations have the same product. As you can see in this example photo the product listed in each city is totally random. There is no pattern.

[image]

The actual data has thousands of products and dozens of locations which is why this can't be done manually. I'd like the data to end up like the following photo, however, if that's not able to be done then another layout which demonstrates some sort of comparison at least in a better format would be helpful.
[image]

I thought using VLookup would be helpful but I don't know how to embrace multiple products and not every location having every product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily handled using a PivotTable.

1. Select cell A1
2. From the Insert ribbon tab, select PivotTable
3. Click OK (accepting all default Create PivotTable settings)
4. In the PivotTable Fields panel on the right, drag Location from the top list to the Columns section
   [image]
5. Then drag Product to Rows
6. Then drag Sales to Values, to get this table:
   [image]

You can make a few significant improvements to appearance by clicking on the PivotTable then going to the Design ribbon tab that appears:
[image]

1. From the Grand Totals menu, turn Off for Rows and Columns
2. From the Report Layout menu, Show in Tabular Form

You can then centre cells and resize columns to get a cleaner table:
[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh your a life saver. I have never used Pivot Tables so i bet this seems like a dumb question! Thanks so much!

Comment: It was clear you weren't familiar with PivotTables, but everyone who knows them had to learn at some point. They're great to play around with. Happy to help.